# VHDL / How to initialize my signal?

Tags: initialization, signals, vhdl, fpga

I'm a beginner in VHDL and I have a basic question.

Let's consider this following input :

```
A  : in std_logic_vector(22 downto 0);
```

And this signal :

```
signal dummyA : std_logic_vector(47 downto 0);
```

I want to initialize dummyA with A so what I did is:

```
dummyA <= A;
```

Is this correct ? I mean is it equivalent to :

`dummyA <= "0000000000000000000000000" & A;` ? Or should I add the 0 explicitly like this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot use `dummyA <= A;` because there is a type mismatch and any good VHDL compiler will reject it.

You might use something like

```
dummyA <= (A'RANGE => A, OTHERS => '0');
```

or (in a sequential context only)

```
dummyA <= (OTHERS => '0');
dummyA(A'RANGE) <= A;
```

or

```
FOR i IN dummyA'RANGE LOOP
    IF i >= A'LOW AND i <= A'HIGH THEN
        dummyA(i) <= A(i);
    ELSE
        dummyA(i) <= '0';
    END IF;
END LOOP;
```

In a concurrent context you could use

```
FOR i IN dummyA'RANGE GENERATE
    IF i >= A'LOW AND i <= A'HIGH GENERATE
        dummyA(i) <= A(i);
    END GENERATE;
    -- ELSE
    IF i < A'LOW OR i > A'HIGH GENERATE
        dummyA(i) <= '0';
    END GENERATE;
END GENERATE;
```

All of the above guarantee that `dummyA(i)` is loaded with `A(i)`.  But `"00000" & A` could cause mis-pairing, if they ranges don't agree at the low end.

Comment: Is `dummyA <= (A'RANGE => A, OTHERS => '0');` equivalent to `dummyA <= "0000000000000000000000000" & A;` ?

Comment: @user2336315: It should be, but you don't have to keep track of how many extra zeros.

Comment: If the range of A is superior of than the range of dummyA, will it truncate datas of A ?

Comment: @user2336315: No, it will fail.  Something like the `FOR` and `IF` combination should be useful if you don't know which vector is larger.

Comment: You could also use the `dummyA <= ext(dummy,dummyA'length);`  That effectively zero pads the MSb's whereas `dummyA <= sxt(dummy,dummyA'length);` performs sign extension padding the MSb's with the most significant bit of the dummy.

Comment: @TOTA: I never know about those functions... looking more closely, it seems to be because they're non-standard.

Comment: How about the second example you brought, `dummyA <= (OTHERS => '0'); dummyA(A'RANGE) <= A;` As signals are assigned after the process is finished, would it work anyway?

Comment: Isn't `dummyA <= (A'RANGE => A, OTHERS => '0');` (your first example) incorrect syntax? I may be wrong, but I don't think the `()` aggregate operator would allow that first part, `A'RANGE => A`, since A is a vector whereas the right-hand side of that assignment would need to be an `std_logic` in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Using a standard function from `ieee.numeric_std` you can do the following to zero pad the MSBs:

```
dummyA <= std_logic_vector(resize(unsigned(A), dummyA'length));
```

---

Although you didn't ask for this, one can also sign-extend like this:

```
dummyA <= std_logic_vector(resize(signed(A), dummyA'length));
```

Although I'd argue in that case that the user should be using a signed data-type for both A and dummyA if they are giving them arithmetic interpretations